# Characteristic polynomial of a $7 \times 7$ matrix whose entries are $5$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, characteristic-polynomial

Avoiding too many steps, what is the characteristic polynomial of the following $7 \times 7$ matrix? And why?

\begin{pmatrix}5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\5&5&5&5&5&5&5\\5&5&5&5&5&5&5\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Hint: zero is an eigenvalue, so such a polynomial will have no constant term.

Comment: another hint: $35$ is another eigenvalue, the eigenvector for this eigenvalue is easy to guess. In addition, quite obviously, the matrix has rank $1$

Comment: Hint: you need no more hints. ;-)

Comment: p(t)=t^7, is it correct?

Comment: no, $t^7$ does not have $35$ as a root

Comment: ok an additional -- well, not a hint, but a suggestion: look at a $2x2$ matrix with the same pattern first (and do _that_ one by calculation)

Comment: For 2x2 matrix I have: p(t)=(5-t)^2-25, ok?

Comment: @Prometeo96 Right, but I'd rather write that as $t(t-10)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was stated in the commentaries, the rank of this matrix is $1$; so it will have $6$ null eigenvalues, which means the characteristic polynomial will be in the form:

$p(\lambda)=\alpha\,\lambda^6(\lambda-\beta) = \gamma_6\,\lambda^6 +\gamma_7\,\lambda^7$

Using [Cayley-Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem):

$p(A)=\gamma_6\,A^6+\gamma_7\,A^7 =0$

Any power of this matrix will have the same format, a positive value for all elements.

$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$

$A = 5\,B$

$A^2 = 5^2\,7\,B$

$...$

$A^6 = 5^6\,7^5\,B$

$A^7=5^7\,7^6\,B$

$p(A) = (\gamma_6+35\,\gamma_7)\,B=0\Rightarrow\gamma_6=-35\gamma_7$

So we have: $\alpha=\gamma_7$ and $\beta = 35$

$p(\lambda)=\alpha\,\lambda^6(\lambda-35)$

Comment: Thanks, but why not assign a value to alfa?

Comment: About $\alpha$, I am not sure, but I think it will always be $(-1)^n$, so in this case it would be $-1$. Anyway, I think it has not much importance, since we are mostly interested in the roots of the polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see, that $v=(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)^T$ is an eigenvector of that matrix. By calculation the corresponding eigenvalue is $35$ (just calculate $Av$).

since the rank of the matrix is $1$ and it has the eigenvalues with their multiplicities as zeros it has to be of the form $p(t) = a t^6 (t-35)$ with $a\neq 0$

Comment: Thanks, but why you not assign a value to a?

Comment: @Prometeo96 If you define the characteristic polynomial as a normalized polynomial then this forces $a=1$. Otherwise it's only determined up to a constant factor.

Comment: Another question: which is the minimum polynomial? How can I calculate it?

Comment: @Prometeo96 consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a matrix $P,$ the columns are eigenvectors of your matrix.   Note that $P$ is not orthogonal, although the columns are pairwise orthogonal.
$$    
P =
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4  &  -1  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  5  &  -1     \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  6    
\end{array}
  \right).
  $$

The columns of $P$ are of varying lengths;  lengths $ \sqrt{7}, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{6}, \sqrt{12},..$ All that is necessary to make an orthogonal matrix $Q$ out of this is to divide each column by its length.